# NPM - how to publish only if tests pass?

Tags: testing, npm, publish, package.json, package-management

I have tests setup for a package I maintain - [create-new-app](https://www.npmjs.com/package/create-new-app). When I run `npm publish`, I want the tests to run first and *only* if they pass, move on to the publish portion. I thought this is what `prepublishOnly` was for. My `prepublishOnly` value looks like this:

```
prepublishOnly: "npm run test"
```

That successfully runs the tests *prior* to publishing, but if the tests fail, it still publishes! How can I get the publish to happen *only* when tests pass?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it's possible that your npm run test command is not returning a proper error code of non-zero